# Project a sequence of 'Left's from a sequence of Eithers?

Tags: scala, seq, either

(Caveat - I'm a scala noob) Given a sequence of `Eithers`, viz

```
theResults : Seq[Either[Error, String]]
```

I am trying to extract all the Errors by using a map on the `left(s)`

```
theResults match {
  case r if r.exists(_.isLeft)  => {
    val errors = theResults.map(r => r.left)
    ...
  }
```

However, this returns

```
Seq[Either.LeftProjection[ErrorResponse, String]]
```

Instead of the `Seq[ErrorResponse]` as I was hoping for.

Please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would probably be:

```
val lefts = theResults.map(_.left.toOption).flatten
```

which will return a sequence of `Error` (or whatever the left type is).

Personally, I think that [`scalaz` Either](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala) is nicer to work with, as it's right-biased...

Comment: Thanks - the end result typing is correct, but is there a way to do this more directly, i.e. to avoid going through `Option`?

Comment: @StuartLC Of course, you can filter the sequence to only include left values, then map over the sequence and `.get` them. It's subjective, but I don't really see how that would improve the clarity of expression (e.g. `theResults.filter(_.isLeft).map(_.left.get)`).

Comment: Thanks - I was simply missing `.left.get`. Will definitely look at using the option / flatten mechanism in future.

Comment: I find `.collect { case Left(e) => e }` more idiomatic. Also why not just `.flatMap(_.left.toOption)` if you're going this route?

Answer (score -3):

How about this?

```
val lefts = theResults.filter(_.isLeft).map(_.asInstanceOf[Left].a)
```